# Get Color from hex in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, colors

How can I get `Color` from hex value in ASP.NET Core?

I found `Color` class in `System.Drawing` namespace, but no appropriate method `FromHex`.

I need to convert values like:

```
#F3A
#2F3682
#83A7B278
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would assume (looking at the documentation for the .NET Standard APIs: https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Drawing.ColorTranslator) that `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator` is not available for .NET Core. If that's the case, does the code you are writing _have_ to target .NET Core? (i.e. can you create a .NET Framework app/library instead)

Comment: I understood, that you need to convert values from the string. Could you specify the destination format for this operation?

Comment: @JamieTaylor I tried with [Google](https://www.google.si/search?q=asp.net+core+hex+to+rgb&rlz=1C1ASUM_enSI731SI735&oq=asp.net+core+hex+to+rgb&aqs=chrome..69i57.11863j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and with [StackOverflow](https://www.google.si/search?q=asp.net+core+hex+to+rgb+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1ASUM_enSI731SI735&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkqMOx8szYAhWI7xQKHeDmD-MQrQIIMigEMAA&biw=1920&bih=1069). I didn't found solution, so I thought this became valid question for SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't found library that would handle alpha, so I write my own.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Color.Library
{
    public class ColorManager
    {
        public static Color FromHex(string hex)
        {
            FromHex(hex, out var a, out var r, out var g, out var b);

            return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
        }

        public static void FromHex(string hex, out byte a, out byte r, out byte g, out byte b)
        {
            hex = ToRgbaHex(hex);
            if (hex == null || !uint.TryParse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var packedValue))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Hexadecimal string is not in the correct format.", nameof(hex));
            }

            a = (byte) (packedValue >> 0);
            r = (byte) (packedValue >> 24);
            g = (byte) (packedValue >> 16);
            b = (byte) (packedValue >> 8);
        }


        private static string ToRgbaHex(string hex)
        {
            hex = hex.StartsWith("#") ? hex.Substring(1) : hex;

            if (hex.Length == 8)
            {
                return hex;
            }

            if (hex.Length == 6)
            {
                return hex + "FF";
            }

            if (hex.Length < 3 || hex.Length > 4)
            {
                return null;
            }

            //Handle values like #3B2
            string red = char.ToString(hex[0]);
            string green = char.ToString(hex[1]);
            string blue = char.ToString(hex[2]);
            string alpha = hex.Length == 3 ? "F" : char.ToString(hex[3]);


            return string.Concat(red, red, green, green, blue, blue, alpha, alpha);
        }
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
ColorManager.FromHex("#C3B271");
ColorManager.FromHex("#CCC");
ColorManager.FromHex("#C3B27144");
ColorManager.FromHex("#C3B27144", out var a, out var r, out var g, out var b);
```

I borrow most of the code from [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) library.

Answer (score 8):

I found that corefx contains System.Drawing.Common, so you can use

```
Color col = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFCC66");
```

Source code can be found here: [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Drawing.Common/src/System/Drawing/ColorTranslator.cs)

Comment: Thanks. Looking the source code, I think it doesn't handle alpha channel.